# Why my font is not working

Tags: html, css, fonts

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            h1{
                @font-face {
                    font-family: bc;
                    src: url("bc.otf") format("opentype");
                }
            }    
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>0123456789 ABCD</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my sample code. Why is my font not working? My font is also not appearing in chrome developer tools.

Comment: If you're running this through IIS, make sure that the MIME type for `.otf` has been added

Comment: What is IIS and where to add MIME type

Comment: [You should do some reading](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608(v=ws.10).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Normally you declare the font-face outside of the element, i.e.

```
 <style> 
    @font-face {
        font-family: bc;
        src: url("bc.otf") format("opentype");
    }

    h1{
        font-family: bc;
    }

</style>
```

other than that check you have placed the font in the correct place

Comment: @AamirMukaram Accept answer?

Answer (score 0):

your `style` should be like this

```
<style>
     @font-face {
        font-family: bc;
        src: url("bc.otf") format("opentype");
     }
     h1{
          font-family: bc;     
      }    
</style>
```